# ASP.NET MVC - pass htmlAttributes as parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, html-helper

I want to pass htmlAttributes as parameter to my HtmlHelper similar as it created in
Html.ActionLink("linktext", "Home", null, **new{width="100px"}**) 
How to pass this new{width="100px"} to my method

```
    public static string SelectCategoryAdminWithAllItem(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string name, **???**)
    { }
```

and how to parse it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked through the source for MVC2 when trying to figure this one out. In MVC2 they used an overload of RouteValueDictionary in System.Web.Routing to turn an object to a dictionary rather than having a helper method available like in MVC3.

```
public static MvcHtmlString TextBox(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string name, object value, object htmlAttributes)
{
    return htmlHelper.TextBox(name, value, new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));
}
```

A bit counter intuitive but that's the standard in 2.

Edit: Updated tags to include mvc2

Answer (score 5):

Always try to look at sources when interested with this kind of questions. From the implementation of HtmlHelper.TextBox

```
public static MvcHtmlString TextBox(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string name, object value, object htmlAttributes)
{
    return htmlHelper.TextBox(name, value, HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes));
}
```

as you see, type of parameter is `object` as you cant use anonymous types as parameters to methods, and `object` is choice. And when parsing it, you can use [HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper.anonymousobjecttohtmlattributes%28v=vs.98%29.aspx)

Comment: I use ASP.NET MVC 2.0, not 3.0 :(